# What's the point for Perl debugger's NONSTOP option?

Tags: perl, debugging

> NonStop
>
> Sets nonstop mode. If a terminal's already been set up, it's too late;
> the debugger remembers the setting in case you restart, though. ([source](http://search.cpan.org/%7Enwclark/perl-5.8.7/lib/perl5db.pl#NonStop))

When is it useful,why do I need to debug if it doesn't ever stop?

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, you can use the debugger in [rendez-vous-mode](http://search.cpan.org/~nwclark/perl-5.8.7/lib/perl5db.pl#STARTUP-ONLY_OPTIONS). In this setting, the debugger runs the application `NonStop` without a tty first, but when an event interrupt occurs, it stops the application and sets the tty up for you to debug.

Update: Rendez-vous-Mode is useful for attaching to a running perl process after it has been started (by something out of your control). If your application is prepared for [dynamically loading the debugger](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Enbugger), you can enter the debugger even if you did not start it with a `-d` option at all.

Comment: And you can also do that programmatically by $DB::single = 1, which is handy for quickly getting to a particular point in execution. There's a good bit more info in perldoc perldebug

Comment: `if true, no i/o is performed until interrupt`,what kind of i/o does it mean here?

Comment: @Je Rog - I very frequently do stuff like: $DB::single = 1 if ( ... my condition ....). Then, when run under the debugger, execution stops at the next statement if the condition is true. It's very handy just before a croak on an internal error, as it allows you to check variable values, etc., before the context is lost. The code has no effect when not run under the debugger, so it's safe to leave in

Comment: @Je Rog: Terminal i/o, displaying a prompt, waiting for commands